# ¿Cuando inicia el winter bash 2018?

Tags: discusión, winterbash-2018

Quisiera agregar una descripción a la pregunta pero creo no hace falta. :)

Ya van 5 dias de este mes y aún no sé nada al respecto. Espero que si haya este año porque incluso tuvimos una edición cuando aún eramos versión beta.

Comment: Según [Winter Bash Stack Exchange](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) quedan 531500 segundos... 531499... 531498... 531497...

Comment: he sido un spam con esto en el chat!!, de hecho los moderadores estan pensando en banearme xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diciembre 12 de 2018 -> [Cuenta regresiva](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)

Fuente [Respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318712/289691) a [When do the holiday hats start appearing again for late 2018?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317724/289691)

NOTA: 18 horas del 11 de diciembre de 2018 hora del centro de México :)

Comment: gracias por el horario para México, siempre ando bien perdido con eso